# Excel Formula Edit to Autofill

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got an Excel spreadsheet that I'm working on, and I'm stuck with this problem.

This is the current formula for one of the cells:

```
=CONCATENATE($A$32,"",$B$32,"",$C$32,"",$D$45)
```

All the data is auto filled and pulled from other cells located in `A32`, `B32`, `C32` and `D45`, etc.

**I would like to add some commas in between data for it to be easier to process later on.**

I came up with this:

```
=CONCATENATE($A$32,"**,**",$B$32,"**,**",$C$32,"**,**",$D$45)
```

However, I can't find for the life of me how to apply THAT change to all the other columns in the spreadsheet.

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+drag, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+drag, but nothing works.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also be able to quickly use Find & Replace.

In the `Find` box type `" "` and in the `Replace` box type `"**,**"`. If you don't have any other formulas with the `" "` in them, you can choose <kbd>Replace All</kbd> or use <kbd>Replace</kbd> to do them one at a time.

[image]

You can switch the `Search:` choice to `By columns` to search down rather than across.

Comment: If you are certain that you won't screw up other formulas this is the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The dollar signs around the cell letter means that it's referencing an absolute cell. Try removing the dollars and then when you drag the cells will change depending on the direction you drag.

If you are having trouble dragging, click the cell you wish to drag and in the lower right corner a black square will appear. Click and drag this square.

Alternatively copy the cell with the formula. Then highlight the cells where you want the formula to be and **Right Click > Paste Special > Formula**